# boto3 lambda script to shutdown RDS not working

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

I'm just starting out with boto3 and lambda and was trying to run the below function via Pycharm.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds')

response = client.stop_db_instance(
    DBInstanceIdentifier='dummy-mysql-rds'
)
```

But i receive the below error:

botocore.errorfactory.DBInstanceNotFoundFault: An error occurred (DBInstanceNotFound) when calling the StopDBInstance operation: DBInstance dummy-mysql-rds not found.

Do you know what may be causing this?

For the record, I have the AWS toolkit installed for Pycharm and can run simple functions to list and describe ec2 instances and my AWS profile has admin access.

Comment: Take a look at region in which you're running the code. If you create `boto3.client` without explicitly specifying region, it will use default region which can be different from region your RDS is in.

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha it's definitely set to the correct region and profile using the AWS toolkit drop down. I suppose i can test by explicitly defining the region and key.

Comment: then it can be something silly like a typo. List all instances with `client.describe_db_instances()` and maybe it will give you a hint

Comment: i ran client.describe_db_instances() and got Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha - i can now see what the issue is. I added a print statement and believe it is looking at the default AWS profile and not the one i have selected in the Pycharm AWS dropdown at the bottom right of the screen. I'm now trying to determine how to explicitly tell it to use my AWS profile

Comment: My initial guess was correct then. You can set env variable `AWS_PROFILE` if everything else fails

Comment: rds = boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='dev')

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha i added the above line and it fixed the issue. Although Pycharm can detect all 7 of my AWS profile credentials, it keeps defaulting to "Default". Seems like a bug because in the AWS Explorer window in the left it picks up the correct profile based on the one selected from the profile drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

By explicitly defining the profile name the below function now works via Pycharm. Thank you @OleksiiDonoha for your help in getting this resolved.

```
import boto3
rds = boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='dev')
client = boto3.client('rds')

response = client.stop_db_instance(
    DBInstanceIdentifier='dev-mysql-rds'
)
```

Comment: you dont need to put that directly into your code. You can pass this while running the script like

AWS_PROFILE=testprofile myscript.py